# Is Chain of Responsibilities suitable for creating DAG like pipelines?

Tags: java, kotlin, design-patterns

I understand that the CoR pattern is used when we have a sequence of tasks that need to be carried out, each takes the previous output as input and produces some new output.

Now I would like to see if I can apply this pattern to create non-linear pipelines. I have something like this in Kotlin:

```kotlin
interface Handler<I, O> {
    fun handle(input: I): Result<*>
}
```

How can I make it so that I can implement something like the following with concurrent execution path?

```
Peel mangos (Mango -> PeeledMango)
|
Dice mangos (PeeledMango -> DicedMango)
|    
|
|    Peel bananas (Banana -> PeeledBanana)
|    |
|    Dice bananas (PeeledBanana -> DicedBanana)
|  /
|/
|
Blend (DicedMango, DicedBanana, Yogurt, Milk -> MangoBananaSmoothie)
```

UPDATE:
To elaborate a little bit more. What I'm looking for is a DAG graph-like framework, in which a Handler could depend on outputs of more than one Handlers.

If we are making a mango-only smoothie, I can do the following easily:

```kotlin
// Construct the chain in reverse
val blender = Blender()
val addYogurtHandler = AddYogurtHandler(next = blender)
val addMilkHandler = AddMilkHandler(next = addYogurtHandler)
val diceMangoHandler = DiceMangoHandler(next = addMilkHandler)
val peelMangoHandler = PeelMangoHandler(next = diceMangoHandler)

// Kick off the chain
val smoothie = peelMangoHandler.handle(mango)
```

But I cannot seem to find an easy way to extend this pattern to add more extra dependencies.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what do you ask. Implementation of the above using Kotlin coroutines would be something like: `val dicedMangos = async { dice(peel(mangos)) }; val dicedBananas = async { dice(peel(bananas)) }; val smoothie = blend(dicedMangos.await(), dicedBananas.await, yoghurt, milk)`. You can pretty easily adapt this to your `Handler` interface. But it looks like you need some kind of a graph framework or something.

Comment: @broot Yes, that's what I'm asking. Updated the post to elaborate more.

Comment: What you're describing initially is the [pipes-and-filters](https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PipesAndFilters.html) architecture. Totally unrelated to the Chain of Responsibility pattern. In CoR, only _one_ "link" handles each request. The pattern is _not_ a pipeline.